# Access 2007 Joining a list to many fields

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

So I have a table with a list of Names, Dob, address etc.

I have a second table where I want to list teams names and their players (9 players per team).

So each row will have 9 names from the table Names. And for the life of me can't figure out how to make a link between them, as one person can be in many teams. (This is why it's weird.)

I can't post the database because of confidentiality.

Comment: this is possible, but the structure is questionable.  Why not have a table with two columns?  Team Name and Player -- you'd have 9 rows for every team.

Comment: There is a many-to-many relationship between players and teams. Make a table for each (which you seem to have done already), and a third table called a "junction" table. The junction table lists the Player Id and Team Id for each instance of membership. The junction table will have a one to many relationship with both the players and teams tables. [See here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-many-to-many-relationship-eeb77a8c-8891-4965-81d6-b2a7329ce449)

Comment: Please edit into your question a specific example with what you see as the relevant properties of your design so precise things can be said in answers and comments.

Comment: What does "make a link between" mean? Why do you want to "make a link"? Please summarize your relevant "research" (per downvote mouseover info). (You seem to have heard a rumour about something about database design? What *reference(s)* telling you about database design are you using?)

Comment: Your title says "join" but your question says "make a link". "Join" is an operator on tables that returns a new table. Please clearly explain what you are trying to do. Preferably with an example with example input and output.

Answer (score 0):

By a "link" you presumably mean a "FK (foreign key) constraint". A FK is a set of columns in a table whose subrow values must appear as subrow values for some CK (candidate key). (A CK is a candidate for PK (primary key)). FKs (and cardinalities) follow from the criterion for rows going in a table (its *predicate*) and what situations/states can arise (per *business rules*). A FK constraint declaration tells the DBMS about a FK.

Each of your team table player name column values has to be a player table name value. So there is a FK from each team table player name column to the player table name column. Eg in SQL `FOREIGN KEY Team (player1) REFERENCES Player (name)`.

You need to read an introduction to information modeling and relational database design. ([To query or update re a business situation you need predicates, but not FKs or cardinalities.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193358/3404097))

PS When does a row go into the team table? For a given team is there one row, or 9! rows, or 9 to the 9th rows? If just one then which one? (Typically, the subrow that is the "smallest" according to some order.) But those are bad designs. Typically we would have a predicate "team *name* has player named *player*". But typically we would have predicates "player with id *id* has name *name*..." & "team *name* has player with id *id*". But etc. Etc etc. Read a book.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your schema look like this:

[image]

It consists of three tables and two relationships (links).  You may want additional fields for your purposes.  I take it you know how to create tables.  I'm guessing you also know how to create links.  If not, try asking Access for help with "relationships".