# How to model students/courses/grades?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I want to have a database which contains each student, the courses he/she is attending and the grades he/she has for each of them.

My current model is:

---

**STUDENT:**
first_name
last_name
student_id `PK`

**COURSE:**
course_name
course_id `PK`

**GRADES**
grade
student_id `FK`
course_id `FK`

---

The problem is that I can't join STUDENT and COURSE. Would it be ok to add student_id as a foreign key in COURSE? What would the best modelling be?

Comment: You need a 4th table. Courses can be taken by many students. Consider calling it **ENROLLMENTS**. Technically, you could cram all of the information into grades, but then you would have use them as placeholders and then mutate them at course completion time. Courses cannot depend on a single student.

Comment: Please explain what rows you want: rows where *student_id* ids a student and *course_id* ids a course and ...".

Answer (score 0):

Any two tables can be meaningfully joined. It just apparently isn't going to give you the rows you want. Please explain what rows you want: rows where *student_id* ids a student and *course_id* ids a course and ..."? In fact you need to give such a *predicate* for every base table or the database can't be used. You seem to be expecting us to know what those are from common sense. But it's not clear what rows you want that that join isn't giving you.

A FK (foreign key) just says values for some column set are also values for some other column set. That, like every constraint, follows from what rows you want put in each table in a situation and what situations can arise. So decide what rows you want to be able to ask for and if they aren't returned by some query using the base tables you have then add appropriate base tables. Then declare consequent constraints, including FKs, PKs (primary keys) & UNIQUE, so the DBMS can prevent impossible updates. But note that constraints are not needed to query. A query expression just uses base table names and the rows returned satisfy predicates built from base table predicates.

Presumably you want rows where "student *student_id* takes class *class_id*. Grades is presumably rows where "student *student_id* made *grade* in class *class_id*". Projecting out *grade* from Grades gives rows where "student *student_id* made some grade in class *class_id*". But those are only the rows you want if all students enrolled in a class have a grade for it.

You could add Enrollment(student_id, class_id) with predicate "student *student_id* takes class *class_id*. Notice that then a row in Grade must be a subrow in Enrollment, so we declare a FK; that just reflects the fact that "if student *student_id* made some grade in class *class_id* then *student_id* takes class *class_id*".

Or you could instead have Grade's predicate be something like "student *student_id* made *grade* in class *class_id* or student *student_id* takes class *class_id* and *grade* = 'n/a'". Then a projection of Enrollment gives you the rows you want. Notice how that predicate is relatively complex. This is one of the difficulties with using NULL in SQL or other special values.

Re querying see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193358/3404097) and/or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318188/3404097) (including their links).